# PHP mail() function on windows uses From: header as MAIL FROM value

Tags: php, windows, email

It seems that when I use the code similar to:

```
$name = "Some Name";
$account = "account@domain.com";

$headers = "From: " . $name . " <" . $account . ">\n";

mail($sometarget, $somesubject, $somedata, $headers,
    "-f" . $account);
```

to send e-mails, mail() function on windows is using "From:" header value (here: "Some Name ") instead of value forced by "-f" parameter (here: "account@domain.com") effectively ignoring this parameter. This causes problems on some e-mail servers.

Any ideas how to change this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the note about additional_parameters on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I've read the note. I don't see any explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

u can use [PEAR Mail package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) and send email via smtp server. mail function has problems in windows servers.

Comment: Yeah I know, I could also use plain sockets and talk to SMTP server as well, but it doesn't answer my question. If "-f" parameter is ignored in windows then, why:
- it is not documented anywhere
- mail implementation is not following RFC while extracting data form "From:" header - it should use mail address between < and >